# Ubuntu 14.04 : wifi, change DHCP to static

Tags: postfix, static-ip

I'm trying to install a mail server (using Postfix) on an Ubuntu VM. I have a dynamic IP so I'm using No-ip.

I tried to change DHCP to static, but

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Just display this :

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, your interfaces are assigned their address by *Network Manager*.

*Network Manager* is incompatible with `/etc/network/interfaces`.

So, Ubuntu solves it like this. If an interface is not mentioned in `/etc/interfaces` at all, it is left on the hands of *Network Manager*.

With *Network Manager*, you can use Ubuntu's graphical utilities to configure it...

1. Click on the *Control Gear*, then select *System Settings*.
2. Click on the *Network* folder.
3. Options.
4. IPv4 Settigs tab.
5. Manual method.
6. Make sure the *Available to all users* is checked.
7. Set the fields as you desire.

On the other hand, it you desire to use the `/etc/network/interfaces` method, just add the correct lines as appropiate. Network Manager will see that you have configured it, and will refuse to touch it with a 10 foot pole.

Note however that it is enough for you to mention an interface on the configuration files for *Network Manager* to react like this.

Comment: In that case, please vote my answer up...

Comment: Done, didn't know about this functionality :)